# Ps2pdf: checking version on a Windows machine

Tags: ghostscript, ps2pdf

I use TexLive 2011 and `Ghostscript 9.05` on `Windows XP`. I see that my WinEdt when calling `ps2pdf` for the `ps > pdf` conversion is using `Ghostscript 9.04` (which I do not have anymore on my machine).

Thus I would like to verify from the command prompt in Windows the version of `ps2pdf`. Which command to use?

A related question: Is `gswin32c.exe` called by `ps2pdf.exe` ?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ps2pdf -v -` should show you the version of Ghostscript (`gswin32c.exe`). It should be the same as `rungs -v` (GS used internally by TL).